# POSTvalue of a select populated by Ajax in a form

Tags: javascript, php

This may be a very typical task yet i am having issued cracking a solution for it.

I am using a form which has 2 select options in it

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadimage"  method="post" action="" class="allForms">

<select id="parentCatSel" onchange=listsubcategory(this.value)>
<option value="">Choose category</option>
</select>

<div id="subcatcontainer"><select id="subCatSel"><option value="">Choose Sub category</option></select></div>

<input name="save" class="save" type="submit"  id="save" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Based on the category chosen in "parentCatSel" the "subcatcontainer" is populated with a select option of subcategories
for the chosen parent category
listsubcategory()

returns

```
 <select id="subCatSel"><option value="">Choose Sub category</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option></select>
```

the display of subcategory works fine with no errors, however when i try to post the values in the form , i am not able to retrieve the value of chosen option in  "subCatSel" as below

```
    document.getelement['subCatSel']= null
post['subCatSel'] = null
```

please suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Add name attribute to your select inputs.

```
<select id="subCatSel" name="subCatSel"><option value="">Choose Sub category</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, my terrible bad of coding in the actual code. I missed out on a quote in the select

just changed that to

it works as wanted!!, thanks everyone